# Can Ghost kill White Walkers or Wights?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03 we see Ghost charging with the Dothraki to fight the dead army, but could he kill them?

If no, how could he be useful in that charge?

Comment: in case you didn't notice them, there was a few dozens of wight between Winterfell and White Walkers

Comment: Thanks to Plot Armor he survived a flood of Wights while Dothrakis on Horses couldn't. Bran's direwolf died with like 10 - 20 Wights around him, but the Plot Armor in this season saved him as well.

Comment: @DeepakKamat, being post-production CGI wolf he stopped existing when charged into darkness, and only appeared back after the dawn.

Comment: @user28434 as a post-production CGI wolf myself, I can confirm this as 100% true.

Comment: Maybe Ghost can pull a reverse-warg and channel some post-Valyrian hero powers :-)

Comment: @KeineMaster Profile pic checks out!

Answer (score 18):

To drop this to an answer, from comments...

I think we can assume Ghost *can* kill wights, though not White Walkers.

White Walkers can be killed only by dragon glass or Valyrian steel.

Wights, on the other hand, we have seen killed many times by more 'simple' mechanical means - blow them up, decapitate them, or otherwise heavily dismember. <sup>[1]</sup>

We have on the odd occasion seen that a surviving hand can move on its own  but I think that has only happened when it was 'just' dismemberment, ie the rest of the wight was still 'alive'.
I checked the wight at King's Landing (S07E07) - that was in 2 halves & still both halves moving, then the hand was removed & that kept moving. Jon killed it with dragon glass [whilst telling everyone it was that or fire, even though we've already seen otherwise at Hardhome (S05E08).]

<sup>[1]</sup>  Arrow in the head; trod on or pulled in half by a giant; couple of sword-thrusts through the body; axe in the back - all these from Hardhome.

Comment: I suppose they might not be killed by being dismembered, but maybe making them harmless is enough.

Comment: This may end up being inconclusive. It is said they can only be killed by those three, yet in the books dragon glass did nothing, it needed regular steel. The TV seems to change its mind over time. The wights were shuffling zombies until Bran got to where the Children were, then suddenly they were speed-merchants.

Comment: Are you sure about that first part? Dragon glass appears to work against wights (see Small Paul), but it shattered on the armour the wight was wearing. Dragon glass might be super effective, it's still just dragonglass.

Comment: See the discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50109089

Comment: I don't think fire can kill White Walkers - even Dragonfire

Comment: Yeah, I'm rethinking this; so far I can find no evidence for or against for fire being effective on white walkers except the night king... wights on the other hand, canon seems to say only fire will kill them, dragon glass has no effect [book] but steel does [book & TV]. I need to watch more battles to be certain. Anyone know offhand the episode number of the fight north of the wall where Dany turns up with the dragon?

Comment: @Tetsujin there is evidence against WW being vulnerable to fire. During Hardhome we see one step through flames to attack Jon.

Comment: Yeah, looking back at Hardhome - there is, I think, sufficient evidence in the shot of him walking through the fire that he was 'suppressing' it, in a similar way to the Night King.

Answer (score 15):

Wights can be killed by fire, dragonglass or valyrian steel. Ghost has none of those, so is useless.

Note that the same went for the Dothraki until their Arakhs were set on fire.

Comment: Plot armor was very high in this season. Sam survived, Mormont survived until he protected Dany till the end, Jaimie, Brienne, Tormund, Ghost, Jon etc. Very bad writing and not Game of Thrones at all.

Comment: Wights can be killed by 'simple' mechanical means, blow them up or decapitate. We've seen it many times. White Walkers need the 'special' treatment, not wights.

Comment: @Tetsujin doesn't your comment an answer then?

Comment: @tetsu, didn't we had simple hand, and body part moving on the flood back when Jon was visiting the Northmen? Or is my memory playing trick again?

Comment: @DragandDrop - I checked we had a solo hand moving at King's Landing, but the rest of the wight was 'alive' too. I might need a hand [so to speak] to find other examples, there's a lot of material to go through, with no real index to search ;) I dropped in an answer with what I have so far.

Comment: How do you know they didn't plate his teeth with Dragonglass?

Comment: @Möoz how do you know ghost can't breathe fire? Should I put that in the answer?

Comment: @Tetsujin yet we saw them charge at the humans at full speeds with all kinds of weapons. Livings things can get killed easily, one knife into the eye and gone. But even if you strangle a wight by its throat or put a knife in their body it won't affect them one bit. So I bet my money on ghost dying on the first charge.

Comment: @DeepakKamat - really, don't bet money on it... we've already seen him in the e04 teaser.

Comment: I know he is in the teaser, I am betting my money on a Direwolf not surviving a flood of wights.